# How to fix the grid-area problem in css because my photo's won't show up

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

So I had to make a webpage with CSS Grid areas.
After I wrote my css and went to the inspector, I saw my grid so it worked. But my photos didn't show up.. Why?

I've noticed that a part of the grid was filled when I put the grid-area-name in brackets but in tutorials, this is not how it works.

If I'm doing something wrong, let me know!

My code

```
    <header>
  <nav>
      <img src="Logo.png" width="30%" height="30%">
      <ul>
          <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Gallery</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </header>

      <main>
        <div class="grid">
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
        </div>
      </main>


 </body>




        html {
          root: font-size: 62.5%;
        }

        header {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100vw;
          position: relative;
        }

        img {

          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: center;
        }

        nav {
          display: block;
          border-bottom: solid 4px black;
          text-align: center;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;

        }

        nav li {
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding: 8px 13px 8px 3px;
        }



        nav a {
          color: black;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        main {
          height: 700vh;
          width: 100vw;
        }

        .grid {
          background-color: black;
          height:700vh;
          width: 100vw;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 1fr)  ;
          grid-row-gap: 20px;
          }

        .grid div {
          grid-row: 1;
          background-image: url(https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2018/08/19/15347041965884.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(2) {
          grid-row: 2;
          background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56cb3b9d7c65e45c27f93388/t/5aa64e3824a694a840e74d32/1522767740629/Ini-main.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(3) {
          grid-row: 3;
          background-image: url(http://xevathethao.vn/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/18-ban-thang-cua-doi-truong-huyen-thoai-puyol-cho-barca-205718.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(4) {
          grid-row: 4;
          background-image: url(https://nieuws.medialaancdn.be/sites/nieuws.vtm.be/files/styles/larger/public/article/image/2013/07/villa.jpg?itok=K5ii24ZZ);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }





        .grid div:nth-child(5) {
          grid-row: 5;
          background-image: url(https://www.vi.nl/.imaging/mte/vinl-website-theme/760x506/dam/articles/artikelen/2013/03/13/xavi_1024.jpg/jcr:content/xavi_1024.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(6) {
          grid-row: 6;
          background-image: url(https://e0.365dm.com/13/09/800x600/robin-van-persie-manchester-crystal-palace-premier-league_3004821.jpg?20130917113837);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(7) {
          grid-row: 7;
          background-image: url(https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/40d266dcfb50449238c0102d12d49b85?width=1024);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;

        }

        .grid div:nth-child(8) {
          grid-row: 8;
          background-image: url(https://i.eurosport.com/2018/12/07/2477900-51456710-2560-1440.jpg?w=1050);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }




        .grid div:nth-child(9) {
          grid-row: 9;
          background-image: url(http://voetbal24.be/UserFiles/images/news/KevinDeBruyne_092.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(10) {
          grid-row: 10;
          background-image: url(https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/07/25/13/neymar.jpg?w968h681);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(11) {
          grid-row: 11;
          background-image: url(https://www.vi.nl/.imaging/mte/vinl-website-theme/760x506/dam/articles/2018/01/26/vi-9893016.jpg/jcr:content/vi-9893016.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(12) {
          grid-row: 12;
          background-image: url(https://gvacdn.akamaized.net/Assets/Images_Upload/2018/03/30/a13a722c-261b-11e8-8f69-d462fccfe2be_web_scale_0.0597015_0.0597015__.jpg?maxheight=513&maxwidth=767&scale=both);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }




        .grid div:nth-child(13) {
          grid-row: 13;
          background-image: url(http://voetbal24.be/UserFiles/images/news/meunier-032.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(14) {
          grid-row: 14;
          background-image: url(https://s.bundesliga.com/assets/img/1170000/1160064_imgw750.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(15) {
          grid-row: 15;
          background-image: url(https://media1.faz.net/ppmedia/aktuell/sport/3812941919/1.4977873/article_multimedia_overview/fuer-torwart-manuel-neuer-ist.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(16) {
          grid-row: 16;
          background-image: url(https://files.voetbalprimeur.nl/news/2018/03/14/v2_large_17f8e29cf4d3e9fdda3fe1d2627edadd13694765.png);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }



        .grid div:nth-child(17) {
          grid-row: 17;
          background-image: url(https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2018/08/22/15349240203051.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(18) {
          grid-row: 18;
          background-image: url(https://givemesport.azureedge.net/images/18/01/11/13836f4153fb280a9c255eef6c5a3635/960.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(19) {
          grid-row: 19;
          background-image: url(https://www.thenational.ae/image/policy:1.120470:1499269884/image/jpeg.jpg?f=16x9&w=1200&$p$f$w=dfa40e8);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(20) {
          grid-row: 20;
          background-image: url(https://images.cdn.fourfourtwo.com/sites/fourfourtwo.com/files/styles/image_landscape/public/romelu_lukaku_man_united.jpg?itok=ZORZtX_q);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }





        @media (min-width: 600px) {
          .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(17, 1fr);
            grid-template-areas:
            "Messi Messi Messi Messi Iniesta Iniesta"
            "Messi Messi Messi Messi Iniesta Iniesta"
            "Messi Messi Messi Messi Puyol Puyol"
            "Messi Messi Messi Messi Puyol Puyol"
            "Villa Villa Xavi Xavi Robin Robin"
            "Villa Villa Xavi Xavi Robin Robin"
            "Ibra Ibra Eden Eden Eden Kevin"
            "Ibra Ibra Eden Eden Eden Kevin"
            "Ibra Ibra Eden Eden Eden Phil"
            "Neymar Neymar Neymar Eden Eden Phil"
            "Neymar Neymar Neymar Radja Radja Meunier"
            "Neymar Neymar Neymar Radja Radja Meunier"
            "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Neuer"
            "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Robben"
            "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Robbert"
            "Chicha Chicha Forlan Forlan Lukaku"
            "Chicha Chicha Forlan Forlan Lukaku"
          }

          .grid div {
          background-image: url(https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2018/08/19/15347041965884.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Messi;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(2) {
          background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56cb3b9d7c65e45c27f93388/t/5aa64e3824a694a840e74d32/1522767740629/Ini-main.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Iniesta;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(3) {
          background-image: url(http://xevathethao.vn/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/18-ban-thang-cua-doi-truong-huyen-thoai-puyol-cho-barca-205718.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Puyol;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(4) {
          background-image: url(https://nieuws.medialaancdn.be/sites/nieuws.vtm.be/files/styles/larger/public/article/image/2013/07/villa.jpg?itok=K5ii24ZZ);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area:Villa;
        }





        .grid div:nth-child(5) {
          background-image: url(https://www.vi.nl/.imaging/mte/vinl-website-theme/760x506/dam/articles/artikelen/2013/03/13/xavi_1024.jpg/jcr:content/xavi_1024.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Xavi;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(6) {
          background-image: url(https://e0.365dm.com/13/09/800x600/robin-van-persie-manchester-crystal-palace-premier-league_3004821.jpg?20130917113837);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Robin;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(7) {
          background-image: url(https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/40d266dcfb50449238c0102d12d49b85?width=1024);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Ibra;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(8) {
          background-image: url(https://i.eurosport.com/2018/12/07/2477900-51456710-2560-1440.jpg?w=1050);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Eden;
        }




        .grid div:nth-child(9) {
          background-image: url(http://voetbal24.be/UserFiles/images/news/KevinDeBruyne_092.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Kevin;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(10) {
          background-image: url(https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/07/25/13/neymar.jpg?w968h681);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Neymar;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(11) {
          background-image: url(https://www.vi.nl/.imaging/mte/vinl-website-theme/760x506/dam/articles/2018/01/26/vi-9893016.jpg/jcr:content/vi-9893016.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Phil;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(12) {
          background-image: url(https://gvacdn.akamaized.net/Assets/Images_Upload/2018/03/30/a13a722c-261b-11e8-8f69-d462fccfe2be_web_scale_0.0597015_0.0597015__.jpg?maxheight=513&maxwidth=767&scale=both);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Radja;
        }




        .grid div:nth-child(13) {
          background-image: url(http://voetbal24.be/UserFiles/images/news/meunier-032.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Meunier;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(14) {
          background-image: url(https://s.bundesliga.com/assets/img/1170000/1160064_imgw750.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Reus;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(15) {
          background-image: url(https://media1.faz.net/ppmedia/aktuell/sport/3812941919/1.4977873/article_multimedia_overview/fuer-torwart-manuel-neuer-ist.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Neuer;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(16) {
          background-image: url(https://files.voetbalprimeur.nl/news/2018/03/14/v2_large_17f8e29cf4d3e9fdda3fe1d2627edadd13694765.png);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Robben;
        }



        .grid div:nth-child(17) {
          background-image: url(https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2018/08/22/15349240203051.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Robert;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(18) {
          background-image: url(https://givemesport.azureedge.net/images/18/01/11/13836f4153fb280a9c255eef6c5a3635/960.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Chicha;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(19) {
          background-image: url(https://www.thenational.ae/image/policy:1.120470:1499269884/image/jpeg.jpg?f=16x9&w=1200&$p$f$w=dfa40e8);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Forlan;
        }

        .grid div:nth-child(20) {
          background-image: url(https://images.cdn.fourfourtwo.com/sites/fourfourtwo.com/files/styles/image_landscape/public/romelu_lukaku_man_united.jpg?itok=ZORZtX_q);
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          grid-area: Lukaku;
        }

        }
```

Comment: there is no style tag in your code

Comment: @NarenP, css are under html code (please scroll down)

Comment: I am Just saying that css surrounded with <style > tag. Your code is missing <style> tag

Comment: Something is wrong with your media query if you remove it its working

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your media query only
try the following media query it's working for me.

```
 @media only screen (min-width: 600px){
```

Comment: Can you see the pictures in their areas?

Comment: ya . I am seeing pictures in the row wise

Comment: It has to be in a grid-area

Comment: did you tried  @media only screen (min-width: 600px){

Answer (score 0):

Please check comments for your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { /* missing "only screen and" */
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(17, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
        "Messi Messi Messi Messi Iniesta Iniesta"
        "Messi Messi Messi Messi Iniesta Iniesta"
        "Messi Messi Messi Messi Puyol Puyol"
        "Messi Messi Messi Messi Puyol Puyol"
        "Villa Villa Xavi Xavi Robin Robin"
        "Villa Villa Xavi Xavi Robin Robin"
        "Ibra   Ibra   Ibra   Eden Eden Kevin" /* Added third Ibra rather than Eden */
        "Ibra   Ibra   Ibra   Eden Eden Kevin" /* Added third Ibra rather than Eden */
        "Ibra   Ibra   Ibra   Eden Eden Phil"  /* Added third Ibra rather than Eden */
        "Neymar Neymar Neymar Eden Eden Phil"
        "Neymar Neymar Neymar Radja Radja Meunier"
        "Neymar Neymar Neymar Radja Radja Meunier"
        "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Neuer"
        "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Robben"
        "Reus Reus Reus Reus Reus Robert" /* there was incorrect name "Robbert" */
        "Chicha Chicha Forlan Forlan Lukaku Lukaku" /* missed 6th name "Lukaku" */
        "Chicha Chicha Forlan Forlan Lukaku Lukaku"; /* missed 6th name "Lukaku" */
      }
}
```

**UPDATED:**  What if this change helps:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .grid {
        height: calc(150px * 17); /* new */
    }
    .grid div {
        background-position: center center; /* new */
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see images? @StefVerniers

Comment: please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irinpotapova/sn2hgjt3/28/)

Comment: I see images but they aren't in the grid-area

Comment: @StefVerniers, I see, for example, that `Messi` image has 4x4 frames, `Iniesta` - 2x2, `Puyol ` - 2x2, etc. What's wrong? What are you expecting?

Comment: That Messi have a dimension of 4 columns and 4 rows, and next to that photo, 2 photos of Iniesta and Puyol with 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: @StefVerniers, I'm not sure you've asked about this problem in your topic. The main question was that your images are not showing up.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be clear because I've mentioned grid-area as well

Comment: @StefVerniers, could you please try updated version of the answer?